# What does it mean that V3 extensions is the disallowing of remotely hosted code

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Google chrome has just announced that  V3 extensions is the disallowing of remotely hosted code. What does this means ? are they disallowing iframe? I am unable to find any details on this?

Comment: It means you can't load js scripts from external sites. All js code that's used by your extension must be present in the extension package.

Comment: @wOxxOm does that include iframes though? e.g. if your extension had a menu that was really an iframe to another website, would the code for that menu be compliant with this policy?

Comment: It's allowed and is actually an officially supported method to ship remote code because the iframe has normal web permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm noted, it means all of your code must be in the packaged you upload to the Chrome Web Store, you cannot include code from remote servers.

From the [Overview of Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code) docs on [developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com):

> A key security improvement in MV3 is that extensions can't load remote code like JavaScript or Wasm files. This lets us more reliably and efficiently review the safe behavior of extensions when they're submitted to the Chrome Web Store. Specifically, all logic must be included in the extension's package.